# Is it ok to use Audit columns on all the tables in SQL Server(or any other DB)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In my present team we have made it a practice to add 5-6 audit columns in all our tables irrespective of if they are required or not. I am concerned this will increase the number of pages occupied by the tables and the size of the Database.  Once live, the application may have 50k users hitting it concurrently.

How will it impact the performance of the Application ? What should I tell my boss to convince this is a bad policy.

Comment: 6 audit columns is a lot. We use only 2 on all tables, meaning a user who modified the row and datetime of the last modification. That is probably all you really need on ALL tables. I wonder what are other columns? Maybe you need more tables instead of audit columns?

Comment: Just to add more info on the columns, the list of columns is: the first Insert time and user(commonly used but without any business purpose), the latest update user and time(rarely used), a row version column(not used except in a few genuine cases) and a GUID session_id column(again rarely used)

Answer (score 0):

You need to test out and have some data to show .Test the impact with expected workload of 50k users with and with out Audit and document differences like

1.CPU usage
2.Memory Usage
3.IO load

if you are seeing any slowness ,then you can present you boss the testing you have done..

Here is a [whitepaper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015.aspx) from Microsoft which states the impact of Auditing on various oltp workloads

Answer (score 0):

If Size is the concern, you can maintain a separate database or table for the log. Log your changes/operations on tables through triggeres or equivalent SPs created.

Then periodically you can delete the old data.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you convinced this is a bad policy.

They don't take a lot of room.  If you get some performance issues and they are not used you can just remove them and reindex the table.

Is it really a position you want to go to you boss without some hard evidence?